# Is it possible to put JSON-code in metadata-columns?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting, person-or-group

I am using 2 metadata-columns in my SharePoint-List: "Created By" and "Change By". In these columns a name appear of the person who has created or changed the List-item. I would like to have a picture with it. Like the column Person has.

I have used JSON-code but it doesn't seem to work.

Is it even possible?

[image]

"Gemaak door" means "Created By".

Comment: I will suggest you try running this URL in your browser & see if it works: `<siteUrl>/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&accountname=<email-address>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add below Json code in the "Created By" and "Modified By" columns.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "width": "32px",
        "height": "32px",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "border-radius": "50%"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "img",
          "attributes": {
            "src": "='/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&accountname=' + @currentField.email",
            "title": "@currentField.title"
          },
          "style": {
            "position": "relative",
            "top": "50%",
            "left": "50%",
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "auto",
            "margin-left": "-50%",
            "margin-top": "-50%"
          }
        },
        {
          "elmType": "span",
          "txtContent": "@currentField.title"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Strange what ever i do it still does not work :(

Comment: I have updated the Json code. Please check.

Comment: The code does not show my picture

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about SharePoint default "Created By" & "Modified By" columns, it is possible to format this columns using JSON.

I have used the same JSON code in your previous question and it is working fine for me, adding the same code here for reference:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "flex-direction": "column",
    "align-items": "flex-start",
    "margin-top": "6px",
    "padding-right": "8px",
    "width": "100%",
    "overflow": "hidden"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "forEach": "personIterator in @currentField",
      "elmType": "div",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralLight ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary"
      },
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-flex",
        "align-items": "center",
        "height": "28px",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "border-radius": "12px",
        "padding-right": "8px",
        "margin": "2px"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "img",
          "attributes": {
            "src": "='/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&accountname=' + [$personIterator.email]",
            "title": "[$personIterator.title]"
          },
          "style": {
            "width": "28px",
            "height": "28px",
            "display": "block",
            "border-radius": "50%"
          }
        },
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "txtContent": "[$personIterator.title]",
          "attributes": {
            "title": "[$personIterator.title]",
            "class": "nameplate-title"
          },
          "style": {
            "padding-left": "5px",
            "white-space": "nowrap",
            "font-size": "12px"
          }
        }
      ],
      "defaultHoverField": "[$personIterator]"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Note**: This code is for multiple selections of users. It works for both single/multiple selections. But if you want, you can convert it for single selection only.

You can find other supported/unsupported columns in JSON formatting at Microsoft documentation: [Column formatting - Supported column types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#supported-column-types)

---

If this above approach is not working for you then you can try using below in `src` property of `img` element (instead of creating image URL on your own):

```
personIterator.picture
```

As person or group column in JSON supports below properties at this time (sample data):

```
{
   "id": "122",
   "title": "Kalya Tucker",
   "email": "kaylat@contoso.com",
   "sip": "kaylat@contoso.com",
   "picture": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/kaylat_contoso_com_MThumb.jpg?t=63576928822",
   "department":"Human Resources",
   "jobTitle":"HR Manager"
}
```

**Source**: [Column formatting - Special string values](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#special-string-values)

Comment: Frustrating :( Nothing works. I have a feeling we are looking at the wrong direction. Everything i do nothing works. What am i missing?
You show me that it is works and what ever i do nothing works

Comment: When I just adjust for the column Person to show picture without JSON code. It works but I get the pictures smaller. And when i use JSON-code in the "Modify by" column i get a bigger place holder but no picture. In the snapshot that i have posted at the beginning of this question you can see the difference in size very good.